# What do these rim numbers mean?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, rims, carbon

I just noticed these numbers on the inside of my Reynolds AR58 carbon wheel (see picture). The left paragraph seems to provide information about the product and manufacturing date/place. Does anybody know what the numbers/codes in the right paragraph mean?[image: sticker with codes on the inside of the rim]

Comment: ”UD” could stand for “unidirectional” (carbon fibers). Not sure what the other abbreviations mean but it could be the thickness of various carbon (or other fiber) layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're build QC tolerance numbers for side to side (lateral), up and down (radial), and offset (dish).

Comment: QC standing for?

Comment: @piptoma QC is "Quality Control"  generally a stage between manufacturing/finishing and packing/distribution.  Parts that don't meet QC get scrapped or sent back for rework.